# How to implement logic at "masterpage" level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, layout-page

I'm still new to MVC, so bear with me :-)

I've got a community site I'm working on, and I'd like to show how many users are online on all my pages after the user's been logged in.

I've got a shared view which is used as layout for all pages after login (UserLayout.cshtml)

Can I somehow add the logic to show online count to my shared layout ?

If it were WebForms I'd just have some code-behind for my masterpage, but this is obviously not an option here.

The information about users online is fetched from a cache. It's not available as a property on any of my View Models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write an action which renders the information (using a very small view)

You can then call `Html.Action` to render it from the layout page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 'UserLayoutModel' class and have all other view models derive from it. You can also use 'RenderAction' to have a part of the UI rendered separately (make sure you mark this action with ChildActionOnly attribute).

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a BaseController.cs that all controllers inherit from, and in the base controller you can override OnActionExecuting and any viewdata values you set here will be available to your master page.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Global Action Filter.

Normally you add an Action Filter as an attribute to a method or class (`[HttpPost]`). Using a global Action Filter you can add code to every Action, without the need to inherit from a specific class. It is like you added an attribute to each and every Action method.

[This article explains a lot.](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx)